# Get List of Black Pixel of a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I' am actually working with a cv::Mat with B&W pixels.
I'am searching for a way to get a list of my black point in this Mat.

Does someone know how to do such thing ?

I want to do that because I want to detect the bounding rect of this points.
(The best is to get them back in a vector)

somekind of :

```
cv::Mat blackAndWhite;
std::vector<cv::Point> blackPixels = MAGIC_FUNCTION(blackAndWhite);
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I want to precise that I want the best practices, the more Opencv compliant as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the `cv::Mat` to check the pixels that are 0, and get the x and y coordinates from the linear index if the matrix is continuous in memory:

```
// assuming your matrix is CV_8U, and black is 0
std::vector<cv::Point> blackPixels;
unsigned int const *p = blackAndWhite.ptr<unsigned char>();
for(int i = 0; i < blackAndWhite.rows * blackAndWhite.cols; ++i, ++p)
{
  if(*p == 0)
  {
    int x = i % blackAndWhite.cols;
    int y = i / blackAndWhite.cols;
    blackPixels.push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I am searching the best implement you know. Something more Opencv compliant.

Comment: My first thought was of cv::compare function, but it returns another cv::Mat, so the problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

This example from OpenCV shows how to do exactly what you want: [Creating Bounding boxes and circles for contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html). Basically, it this:

```
  // ... 
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
  {  
     approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
     boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
     minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
  }
```